# Good Examples of .NET Desktop Applications

Tags: .net, winforms, desktop

I would like to evaluate .NET as a development platform for a desktop application. I am looking for good examples of .NET desktop applications used in the mainstream. The only ones I know of are:

1. Visual Studio (The copy website form
   is one example.)
2. Team Explorer UI
3. Paint.NET
4. Reflector
5. Gnome Do (An app launcher for Gnome; runs on Mono)

I am looking for more examples; open source, freeware or a demo version in that order.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/) is an open source Development IDE for .NET very much like VS.NET written in .NET (iirc it still has some pinvokes, but it is all managed code) and is quite large and feature complete.

You can even get the [source code](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/Download/) for it to look at.

Comment: Awesome! How did I miss this?!

Answer (score 5):

- [Microsoft Expression Blend](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/Overview.aspx?key=blend)
- [TechSmith Jing](http://www.jingproject.com/)

Answer (score 4):

There are lots of desktop apps done in .NET, only most of them are internal/enterprise apps in companies, not mass-market products.

The only downside I see to doing a mass-market desktop app in .NET is the need to distribute the .NET Framework with it. Of course with the advent of Windows Vista, .NET already comes preinstalled.

Comment: .Net comes preinstalled on XP too.

Comment: In fact, you will want to use .NET 3.5 so some sort of distribution is still needed, even on Vista.

Answer (score 3):

[KeePass](http://keepass.info/) is the free, open source, light-weight and easy-to-use password manager.

Comment: You might be interested in this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10543583

Comment: How is it linked to the answer? (Didn't want to flag a Robert Harvey comment.)

Answer (score 2):

Check for WPF(.NET3.5) applications

http://www.thirteen23.com/experiences/desktop/

[WPF app by Frog design](http://www.istartedsomething.com/20080109/frog-design-wpf-sexy-enterprise-software/)

Answer (score 2):

[Windows Live Writer](http://windowslivewriter.spaces.live.com/default.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0)

Answer (score 2):

[Comicster](http://comicster.net)! :)

Answer (score 1):

I have this Game Neverwinter Nights 2, quite a big thing, and it has some SharpZipLib and QWhale DLLs included. Should be dotNet

Answer (score 1):

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82022/are-net-languages-really-making-any-kind-of-dent-in-consumer-desktop-applicatio) from the related questions list.

Most notable are Gnome applications running on Mono/Linux. [Tomboy](http://www.gnome.org/projects/tomboy/), [Beagle](http://beagle-project.org/Main_Page) and [F-Spot](http://f-spot.org/)!

Answer (score 1):

[slimKEYS](http://www.slimcode.com/slimkeys) is written in C# with some p/invokes.

Answer (score 1):

Icarus (screenshots [here](http://www.gallio.org/Screenshots.aspx)), the GUI of [Gallio](http://www.gallio.org/)/[MbUnit](http://www.mbunit.com/) OSS testing platform.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Media Center has a managed API I believe. I'm not sure how much .Net stuff is in WMC, but you can check it out.